# How Print multipage WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

i have a visual and i wish print i multipage .i have more  page to print out each content stay in the StackPanel(it will increase storing datacontext like a Report) i wish create like a pageBreak in the StackPanel to fix the pagesize so begin to print in one more page but i don't know how create this feature.
Do you have nay advice ,trick,help to work out this step  .
Have a happy day and thanks in advance for your attention.